# Update XAML TextBlock with value of public property from other class

Tags: c#, wpf

I have in my C# WPF solution as follows:
Mainwindow with a startupControl (always running)
Dialogwindow with diffent other controls.
A public Helper-class containing some public static properties to indicate what department at customer is active, and for who i have focus on at the moment.

I want simply two XAML textBlocks displayed in my Startupcontrol to show the property names if and when the value for a department or costumer has been set.

I think it could properbly work smooth with some sort of binding, but i dont know anything about bindings, other than they exists.

Is it possible in any way from my controls in my dialogwindow, to change the value of the 2 textblocks in the Startupcontrol ?

As the program is small and I know exactly when the values change, I think i could make a function setting the value ex.:

```
activeDepartmentTextBlock.Text = HelperClass.ActiveDepartment.Name;
```

But from my control.cs in the DialogWindow, it seems to be possible to reach the activeDepartmentTextBlock.

Anyone who can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Since WPF 4.5, binding to static properties with property change notification is quite simple.

The example below assumes that you want to notify about the change of the `ActiveDepartment` property of the HelperClass (and not about the `Name` property of the Department object). In addition to the static property, declare a static event named `StaticPropertyChanged` and fire it when the static property changes:

```
public class Department
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class HelperClass
{
    public static event PropertyChangedEventHandler StaticPropertyChanged;

    private static Department activeDepartment;

    public static Department ActiveDepartment
    {
        get => activeDepartment;
        set
        {
            activeDepartment = value;
            StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ActiveDepartment)));
        }
    }
}
```

You can bind to a static property like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(local:HelperClass.ActiveDepartment).Name}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-wpf) is a good solution but you have static property so you can't use binding infrastructure directly to get notified of updates since there's no [`DependencyObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyobject) (or object instance that implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification)) involved.

If the value does change and you need to update `TextBlock`'s value in main window yo can create a singleton instead of static class to contain the value and bind to that.

An example of the singleton:

```
public class HelperClass : DependencyObject {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveDepartmentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "ActiveDepartment", typeof( Department ),
        typeof( HelperClass ), new UIPropertyMetadata( "" ) );
    public Department ActiveDepartment {
        get { return (Department) GetValue( ActiveDepartmentProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( ActiveDepartmentProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static HelperClass Instance { get; private set; }

    static HelperClass() {
        Instance = new HelperClass();
    }
}
```

So binding will work like in an example below:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:HelperClass.Instance}, Path=ActiveDepartment.Name}"/>
```

It might look like a hard way and that’s it. You can use [events model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/) instead and add the event to your `HelperClass`. MainWindow can add event handler and change `activeDepartmentTextBlock` value when event raised.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    HelperClass.Instance.DepartmentChanged += OnDepartmentChanged;
}

private void OnDepartmentChanged(Department newDepartment)
{
    activeDepartmentTextBlock.Text = newDepartment.Name;
}
```

**Update**. If you want to have the simplest solution you can break encapsulation principle and pass `MainWindow` as a parameter to `DialogWindow` and make `activeDepartmentTextBlock` public. So you will be able to save the link to the `MainWindow` in the `DialogWindow`'s field and just change the text when you need in `DialogWindow`:

```
this.mainWindow.activeDepartmentTextBlock.Text = HelperClass.ActiveDepartment.Name;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks a little too complicated to my level at the moment. I was hoping there was a shortcut to just interacting with the usercontrol. Something like:
    this.Usercontrol.ParentControl.ActiveDepartmentTextBlock = 
    Helper.ActiveDepartment.Name;

Anyway, thank you for your quick and careful answer ...

Comment: @Allan I'm trying to add another one simple solution. Your example will not working because dialogWindow is not a part of visual tree of main window.

Comment: "you can't use binding infrastructure directly to get notified" is wrong. Since WPF 4.5. there is the StaticPropertyChanged event, and also a new Binding Path syntax for static properties.

Comment: Well I tried, but had some issues regarding namespace in my XAML for the StartupControl, so i leave it for now and will read up on the bindingstuff when i get som spare time again. Thanks for your help so far!